# Problema al coger datos de json en python

Tags: python, json, integer

Estoy cogiendo datos de una api en formato json

```
 {
>     "images": [
>         {
>             "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 13167616,
>             "created": "2021-07-13T09:35:56Z",
>             "id": "15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
>             "links": [
>                 {
>                     "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/v2.1/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
>                     "rel": "self"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
>                     "rel": "bookmark"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "href": "http://192.168.1.82:9292/images/15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
>                     "rel": "alternate",
>                     "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image"
>                 }
>             ],
>             "metadata": {},
>             "minDisk": 0,
>             "minRam": 0,
>             "name": "cirrios",
>             "progress": 100,
>             "status": "ACTIVE",
>             "updated": "2021-07-13T09:35:57Z"
>         },
>         {
>             "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 1020264448,
>             "created": "2021-07-11T15:14:03Z",
>             "id": "ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
>             "links": [
>                 {
>                     "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/v2.1/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
>                     "rel": "self"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
>                     "rel": "bookmark"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "href": "http://192.168.1.82:9292/images/ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
>                     "rel": "alternate",
>                     "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image"
>                 }
>             ],
>             "metadata": {},
>             "minDisk": 0,
>             "minRam": 0,
>             "name": "centos",
>             "progress": 100,
>             "status": "ACTIVE",
>             "updated": "2021-07-11T15:14:22Z"
>         }
>     ]
> }
>
```

Los busco así :

```
try:
    result = requests.get(req["images"], headers=headers)
    result_data = json.loads(result.content)
except Exception as e :
    print('0')
    sys.exit("\nError requesting %s, please check conectivity" %(req["images"],))
```

eso para conectarme y luego con esto pillo lo que me interesa

```
for dato in result_data["images"] :
value = str(dato['name'])
value = int(dato['progress'])
```

La cosa es que id, y name me los pilla pero progress, mindisk o minram no, deduzco que es porque no usan comillas?

me da este error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "openstack3.py", line 263, in 
value = json.dumps(float(dato['progress'])),
KeyError: 'progress'

como tendría que declararlo para coger esos datos??

Comment: Si recibes varios datos puede ser que `mindisk` y `minram` no se encuentren en todos

Comment: pero me da error, y con progress también

Comment: Ya esta, basicamente el json me da los datos de las dos imagenes que tengo, centos y cirrios, los errores me dan con mindisk, minram y progress, deduzco que por ser enteros sin comillas

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no escribes las llaves con las mismas minúsculas/mayúsculas.

Esto funciona:

```
for dato in datos["images"]:
    print(f'Progress={dato["progress"]}')
    print(f'minDisk={dato["minDisk"]}')
    print(f'minRam={dato["minRam"]}')
```

produce:

```
Progress=100
minDisk=10
minRam=20
Progress=100
minDisk=30
minRam=40
```

Nota: cambie los valores en el JSON para comprobar que fueran bien recuperados. El JSON quedo así:

```
datos = {
   "images": [
       {
           "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 13167616,
           "created": "2021-07-13T09:35:56Z",
           "id": "15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
           ...
           "links": [
           "metadata": {},
           "minDisk": 10,
           "minRam": 20,
           "updated": "2021-07-13T09:35:57Z"
       },
       {
           "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 1020264448,
           "created": "2021-07-11T15:14:03Z",
           "id": "ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
           ...
           "metadata": {},
           "minDisk": 30,
           "minRam": 40,
           "name": "centos",
           "progress": 100,
           "status": "ACTIVE",
           "updated": "2021-07-11T15:14:22Z"
       }
   ]
 }
```